# Implement PDF417 Barcode in Oracle EBS

Tags: java, barcode

My Requirement is to implement PDF417 Barcode in Oracle EBS.

I saw a Java Class in the following link:

[In a PDF417 barcode where number of columns are fixed, how would I calculate the number of rows required for some text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16898890/in-a-pdf417-barcode-where-number-of-columns-are-fixed-how-would-i-calculate-the)

so:

1. Will this class encode any character to RAW data for the PDF417 Barcode font.
2. How to call this class.
3. which PDF417 font ie ttf file i should use with this class.

Hope I get help on this.